# How to skip a particular date from date_range function and continue in the for loop?

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a scenario in which I am using data_range function in the for loop to create the file path dynamically but the issue is for few dates the file is not present on the path so, I want to skip those dates and continue with other dates.

let say: I am using date_range function from 01/01/2019 to 10/01/2019 and for 05/01/2019 there is no file so I want to skip 05/01/2019 and continue checking 06/01/2019.

```
daterange=pd.date_range(start="2019-01-01",end="2019-01-10")

for date in daterange:
        date=date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
        
        filepath=f's3://aws-workspace/prod/mapfeatures/dt={date}'
        df_clm= spark.read.parquet(filepath)
```

currently the code is throwing error "the path does not exist" because there is on file for the date 05/01/2019. Can anyone please tell me how I can skip 05/01/2019 and continue with 06/01/2019?

Comment: Can you use boto3 to first check the folder exists?

Comment: No, I can not use

Comment: You could also just catch the exception, log it, and continue the loop

Comment: @Hassan can you explain? how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the Python Spark API, but if the read.parquet line throws an exception for missing files, one way to handle it would be to catch that exception and keep looping :

```py
import logging

daterange=pd.date_range(start="2019-01-01",end="2019-01-10")

for date in daterange:
    try:
        date=date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
        
        filepath=f's3://aws-workspace/prod/mapfeatures/dt={date}'
        df_clm= spark.read.parquet(filepath)
    except Exception as e:
        logging.exception(e)
        continue
```